# With Python , How can I query elements in a json formatted column and make them into rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, data-transform

I have a table, that I did not create, in my sql server database that looks like this.

| manager id | employee info |
| --- | --- |
| 123567890123 | [{'emp_name':'ash','emp_id':'123'},{{'emp_name':'brad','emp_id':'234'}] |
| 235678901234 | [{'emp_name':'sarah','emp_id':'345'},{{'emp_name':'ryan','emp_id':'456'}{{'emp_name':'chris','emp_id':'567'}] |

I queried this table and have pulled into pandas dataframe. I want get each emp_name and emp_id for each manager
Below is my desired result.

| manager id | emp_name | emp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123567890123 | ash | 123 |
| 123567890123 | brad | 234 |
| 235678901234 | sarah | 345 |
| 235678901234 | ryan | 456 |
| 235678901234 | chris | 567 |

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: And `{{` should just be `{`

Comment: Assuming `{{` is just a copying error, you can use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse `employee_info`.

Comment: Then you can iterate over the list to create new rows in the resulting df.

Comment: @Barmar. 3 times `'{{'`. It's probably not a copy error and there is no comma to separate different elements (row 2).

Comment: You should talk to whoever *did* create the table, and ask them to fix it.

Comment: See if you require any further clarification from the answers below.  If no more question,  let us know any of the answers best fit for your needs by accepting the answer you choose.  Thanks!

Comment: @barmar it was just a copying error

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to expand list of json into individual json one per row.  Then, use [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to convert the json into columns.

```
df2 = df.explode('employee info').reset_index(drop=True)

df_out = df2.join(df2['employee info'].apply(pd.Series)).drop('employee info', axis=1)
```

**For better performance**, you can **use [`pd.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)** instead of [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to convert the json into columns, as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame(df2['employee info'].tolist())


  emp_name emp_id
0      ash    123
1     brad    234
2    sarah    345
3     ryan    456
4    chris    567
```

Whole set of codes as follows:

```
df2 = df.explode('employee info').reset_index(drop=True)

df_out = df2.join(pd.DataFrame(df2['employee info'].tolist())).drop('employee info', axis=1)
```

**Data Input**

```
data = {'manager id': [123567890123, 235678901234],
 'employee info': [[{'emp_name':'ash','emp_id':'123'},{'emp_name':'brad','emp_id':'234'}],
  [{'emp_name':'sarah','emp_id':'345'},{'emp_name':'ryan','emp_id':'456'}, {'emp_name':'chris','emp_id':'567'}]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df_out)

     manager id emp_name emp_id
0  123567890123      ash    123
1  123567890123     brad    234
2  235678901234    sarah    345
3  235678901234     ryan    456
4  235678901234    chris    567
```

Comment: You assume `employee info` column is not a string but a real python list? Why not.

Comment: @Corralien  Just wild guess.

Comment: I'm agree with that. Maybe the request is executed from Python and chained with Pandas. The idea is good +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to get expected result:

```
import ast

out = df['employee info'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().apply(pd.Series)
  emp_name emp_id
0      ash    123
0     brad    234
1    sarah    345
1     ryan    456
1    chris    567

out = pd.concat([df['manager id'], out], axis='columns')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     manager id emp_name emp_id
0  123567890123      ash    123
0  123567890123     brad    234
1  235678901234    sarah    345
1  235678901234     ryan    456
1  235678901234    chris    567
```

I slightly modified your dataframe:

```
data = {'manager id': [123567890123, 235678901234],
 'employee info': ["[{'emp_name':'ash','emp_id':'123'},{'emp_name':'brad','emp_id':'234'}]",
  "[{'emp_name':'sarah','emp_id':'345'},{'emp_name':'ryan','emp_id':'456'},{'emp_name':'chris','emp_id':'567'}]"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Assuming the syntax problems in the `employee_info` column are fixed.

Comment: @Barmar. Yes I fixed manually. I removed `{{` and added missing `,`.